# Difference between add and put built-in methods?

Tags: apex

When/where is it appropriate to use them?

Is "put" only used for collection?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `add` method is for `List` or `Set`. The `put` method is for `Map`.

```
List<String> collection1 = new List<String>();
collection1.add('foo');

Set<String> collection2 = new Set<String>();
collection2.add('foo');

Map<String, String> collection3 = new Map<String, String>();
collection3.put('foo', 'bar');
```